# How to Check if a specified string occurs after a particular string in PHP?

Tags: php, string

I have a title. I want to check if a specified string occurs after/before particular string in php.

for ex,

```
Title = Director, Employee Representative
```

I want to check if the word `Employee` occurs after/before `Representative` in the title.
If the title contains `Representative`, check if word prior/next to the word is `Employee`

How to do that?

Comment: `strpos($string, 'Employee Representative')`?

Comment: @deceze This is just one case, I have a set of keywords. A generic case would be helpful.

Comment: @user1518659 you can build the `strpos`'d string dynamically, and still use it as a key: `strpos($string, $first.' '.$second)`

Comment: so "employee representative" and "representative employee" are equally good? Search for both, then.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to convert it to an array, e.g: `explode(" ","Employee Representative")`

```
array(
 0 => Employee
 1 => Representative
)
```

Then you can get the key of the word you're looking for (in this case 1) and increment or decrement it to see what word is before or after it.

Comment: my title is Director, Employee Representative. first I need to check if 'representative' is there in the title. If present, then I need to check if 'Employee' is present before/after word representative. If present I ll do something else i ll do some other thing. this is my case @barjonah

Comment: @user1518659 This works. Just iterate this array and then look to the previous index and the next index.